# While protecting sheet, I'd like to disable "Select Locked Cells"

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm using xlwings and I'd like to protect sheet with un-check the "Select Locked Cells". I've tried many trys, such as "AllowSelectingLockedCellls=False", "SelectingLockedCells=False", etc, and I received a meassage from Python console that "TypeError: _Worksheet.Protect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'AllowSelectingLockedcells'".
Is there any way that I can protect sheet and disable "Select Locked Cells"?

```
import xlwings as xw

folder = "C:\\Python\\DF\\"
xls = "65982.xlsx"

book = xw.Book(folder + xls)
book.app.visible = True
sht = book.sheets["Sheet1"]

sht.api.Protect(DrawingObjects=False, Contents=True, Scenarios=True,
        UserInterfaceOnly=False, AllowFormattingCells=False, AllowFormattingColumns=False,
        AllowFormattingRows=False, AllowInsertingColumns=False, AllowInsertingRows=False,
        AllowInsertingHyperlinks=False, AllowDeletingColumns=False, AllowDeletingRows=False,
        AllowSorting=False, AllowFiltering=False, AllowUsingPivotTables=False)
book.save()
```

Comment: Are you sure this information actually gets stored in the spreadsheet file at all? Maybe it's just something that the Excel program implements.

Comment: Even in Excel, the `Select Locked Cells` is not part of `.Protect` method. You can confirm that in [Worksheet.Protect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect). This property is a part of the Worksheet object as shown in [Worksheet.EnableSelection property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.enableselection). For example `Sheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells`. Check if python allows that.. Something like  `sht.EnableSelection = 1` or `sht.api.EnableSelection = 1` **Disclaimer** I have not worked with xlwings.

Answer (score 1):

As @Siddharth Rout states in his comment these are controlled by `EnableSelection`.

In the following code I remove the locking on cell 'A1' then apply one of the 3 options for EnableSelection;

`xlNoSelection` means I **cannot** select any cell when protection is enabled.
`xlNoRestrictions` means I **can** select any cell I choose when protection is enabled.
`xlUnlockedCells` means I **can only select cells that are unlocked** when protection is enabled. I.e I can select 'A1' on the sheet but no other cell.

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import EnableSelection

excel_file = 'test.xlsx'
with xw.App(visible=True) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(excel_file)
    ws = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

    ws.range('A1').api.Locked = False

    """ 
       Enable one of the following to set the specified requirement 
    """
    ### Not able to select any cells ###
    ws.api.EnableSelection = EnableSelection.xlNoSelection
    ### Select any cell ###
    # ws.api.EnableSelection = EnableSelection.xlNoRestrictions
    ### Select unlocked cells only ###
    # ws.api.EnableSelection = EnableSelection.xlUnlockedCells

    ws.api.Protect(Password='test')

    wb.save()
```